# Main form randomly dissappears after a reboot of CE device

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I have an app written in C#.Net which is running on a Motorola MC67 Windows Mobile device.

Through the "Startup" folder my app is automatically launched after a reboot which loads a "Logon" screen. It was reported that occasionally after a reboot the device is displaying a blank white screen.

At this stage, the software has not crashed as I am able to use some of the devices physical buttons to move to a new screen and then navigate back to the "Logon" screen which now displays correctly.

I am having trouble finding the route of the problem and would appreciate some assistance.

The problem seems to only occur while it is docked (it happens more in a 4 way dock compared to a single dock as the 4 way does more networking) and as it is after a reboot it is difficult to debug.

The white screen that is shown is a splash screen that is displayed while the app launches and just sits in the background so it appears that the "Logon" screen has somehow been hidden or disposed.

As a temp solution I have created a method called "Form_Deactivate()" that is called whenever the "Logon" screen loses focus and when it does I call "this.BringToFront()" which then displays the "Logon" screen correctly and no longer displays the white screen.

Although this probably is an acceptable fix I am still trying to find the cause of the problem.

If it helps, when the deactivate method is called I force an exception in order to log the stack trace but this hasn't really helped me.

```
at InSync.LogonForm.Form_Deactivate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnDeactivate(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
at InSync.ApplicationManager.Start()
at InSyncLauncher.Program.Main()
```

If anyone has any suggestions or things that I could try to get to the bottom of this issue I would be grateful, thanks.

Comment: It sounds like generic windows "crap" is still going on when your app loads, and so other things are taking focus and control and still fidgetting with  whats going on

Comment: Could you please post your Code of this starting routine? Are you using Motorola AppCenter? I would recommend this to you. AppCenter can handle an automatic start of a program and restricts access to the operating system for a normal User.

Answer (score 0):

First, the API functions your app and the Compact Framework uses may not be ready to be used when your app is started with a lnk in \Windows\Startup. There is a native function [IsAPIReady](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885686.aspx) to check for the different API sets.

Secondly, the OS system may load another window to foreground, for example the Home screen. So your app should use a timer to bring the login form to foreground periodically or use [GetForGroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms929244.aspx) periodically to check if the foreground window handle is the Login window (or your current active window).

If you want to write a kiosk mode app, there are many more situations you have to check periodically to prevent the user from getting outside the kiosk app.